# What size are Campagnolo Ultra Torque bottom bracket bearings?

Tags: bearings, campagnolo

I was unable to find the dimensions of Campagnolo bottom bracket bearings. My understanding is that bearings have standard sizes with names like "6200", "6201", etc. See [this chart](https://www.microbluebearings.com/bearing-size-charts/) for a big list.

Knowing the size would allow me to buy compatible bearings from manufaturers other than Campagnolo, which might offer better performance for the money.

What size are Campagnolo Ultra Torque bearings?

---

**Edit**

I am interested in the *ITA and BSA threaded variants*. If anyone can source the [full list](https://www.campagnolo.com/media/files/035_40_Technical%20manual%20-%20Ultra%20Torque%20Power%20Torque%20bottom%20bracket%20cup%20-%20Campagnolo__Rev02_06_16.pdf) then I'm sure others would find that helpful too.

- ITA threaded
- BSA threaded
- BB30
- BB86
- PF30
- BB RIGHT
- BB386

Comment: Campy Ultra Torque is a family of bottom brackets (see [this document](https://www.campagnolo.com/media/files/035_40_Technical%20manual%20-%20Ultra%20Torque%20Power%20Torque%20bottom%20bracket%20cup%20-%20Campagnolo__Rev02_06_16.pdf). What you need to do is figure out what bottom bracket standard you have (BB30, BB86, PF300 etc etc etc) to find the correct bearing size.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus Thanks, I have updated the question

Answer (score 2):

I was able to find an answer on the Wheels Manufacturing Page with a bit of Googling.

https://wheelsmfg.com/crankset-tech

Looks like Campy Power and Ultra Torque use a 25mm axle and 6504 size bearings.

The Ulta Torque crank requires 6504N bearing. I believe the N post-fix means that outer bearing shell has a snap-ring groove into which a retaining clip on the bearing cup fits.

See https://koyo.jtekt.co.jp/en/support/bearing-knowledge/6-3000.html

Comment: The link says Ultra Toruqe is *6805N*

Comment: Also, the N suffix *may* denote that the bearing has a non-standard depth of 6mm, rather than the normally specified 7mm. I am attempting to obtain more info.

Answer (score 0):

I've obtained information that is both consistent *and* inconsistent with Argenti. This page by [Fairwheel Bikes](https://fairwheelbikes.com/hsc-campagnolo-ultra-torque-ceramic-bearing-set/) says:

> Due to ongoing changes in Campagnolo’s Ultra Torque design, it is very important you know exactly which bearing size you require before ordering your HSC ceramic bottom bracket kit. Over the years, Campy has changed from a 6805w7 bearing, to a 6805w6 bearing being used in their Ultra Torque bottom brackets. Essentially, the only difference is in the width of the bearing, varying from 7 mm to 6 mm (Hence the”w7” and “w6”).

That is, the standard specification for 6805 bearings is a 37mm outer diameter, a 25mm inner diameter (NB, the Ultra Torque spindle is 25mm wide), and a 7mm depth. At least some Ultra Torque bearings for threaded BB shells have a 6mm depth. I believe that the N suffix actually denotes this slightly shallower depth.

I am not certain when this change was made. I have found several forum threads where users refer to the 6805N bearings, such as this [2012 thread on Weight Weenies](https://weightweenies.starbike.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=101953), this [2015 thread on Road Bike Review](https://forums.roadbikereview.com/components-wrenching/aftermarket-generic-bearings-campy-ultra-torque-345818.html), and this [single 2018 post on Road.cc's forum](https://road.cc/content/forum/247336-campagnolo-ultra-torque-bearing-conundrum). Thus, I'd recommend you measure the bearing with a vernier caliper to be sure.

There may be additional suffixes denoting the type of seals. I can't confirm, but I would guess that your bearings came with full-contact rubber seals on both sides. The suffix for that seal arrangement is -2RS. I would probably default to getting a bearing with full-contact seals. The suffix -RD, as shown on Argenti's link, should denote a low-contact seal, and -2RU should denote a non-contact seal. These will produce lower friction, but also less protection against dirt or water intrusion. You will need to maintain the bearing more frequently. Oddly, I found a ceramic bearing sold by [Aire Velo](https://www.airevelobearings.com/product/6805n-2rs-hybrid-ceramic-bearings-low-contact-pair/) that uses the -2RS suffix but describes the seals as low-contact, so I'm not sure the suffix terminology is used consistently all the time.

Do note that you can pry the seals off carefully, flush the bearing with WD-40, and re-grease it with regular grease (you'll need a grease gun). This may save you from having to replace the bearing entirely.

Comment: Bearing code suffixes are completely unique to the manufacturer....  a -2RS may mean completely different things for different manufacturers.