# Ekar compatibility with UT bb and 6805 bearing

Tags: bottom-bracket, compatibility, bearings, campagnolo

So I've got ekar chainset and pro tech bb, didn't have a correct bearings so fitted 6805 which are 7mm width, because its 1mm wider than original I've got +2mm over. Cannot see if it's pulling enough both chainset pieces. Do think it's safe? And did anyone tried similar combination before?

Comment: I feel like this would cause wear on the spindle joint and damage the spindle halves...

Comment: That's what i thought as well, but its really hard to tell when it's inside the frame.. but yeah 2mm is quite big gap, so under pressure it will start showing wearing signs . Probably better not to risk and get 6mm

Answer (score 1):

For those who don't know, Campagnolo cranks [use a non-standard version of the 6805 bearing](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/66277/what-size-are-campagnolo-ultra-torque-bottom-bracket-bearings/66281#66281) that's 1mm thinner than the standard bearing. Thus, the standard bearings will push everything 1mm outward on each side.

Modern cranksets will not tolerate that amount of change in the system. Campy and Shimano cranks require a splined interface to engage. If you add 2mm of clearance into the system, the spline won't be fully engaged. Now imagine that you are pedaling. Almost all riders probably cruise at well over 100W of power, and peak power during a sprint is much higher. If you put that amount of power into a splined system that isn't engaged fully, the splines are going to get damaged.

For SRAM cranks, there is a preload adjuster to take up variations in BB width that are within the allowed tolerance of the system. However, it is not going to be designed to take up 2mm additional slack - that's the difference between the widths of BSA and Italian BB shells. Basically, the same issue will happen.

Comment: Hi and thank you! You've been very informative!  Appreciate your help

Comment: Done little bit more research on this one and find out that campag use 6805N bearing which is same 6805 37×25 but N stands for narrow which is 6mm instead of 7mm.
At least it's clear now in my head 
Thanks again for knowledge sharing! Any issues I will come back here.
One love

Comment: @Akapat would you consider accepting this as the answer?  this site works by upvoting and accepting answers.

Comment: Yes, definitely! And thank you again.

Comment: The tolerance for threaded BBs appears to be ±0.5mm after reviewing SRAM and Shimano’s frame design documents. So a 2mm abnormality would be bad.